# expo app with testing react-native-testing-library and jest-native "has no exported member 'toHaveProp"

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I'm trying to use jest-native as extra matchers and i'm having an installation problem i think
...
I am on a react-native ts app with expo and here are my versions:

- **expo**:"~39.0.0"
- **@testing-library/react-native version**:"^7.1.0"
- **jest-preset**: 'jest-expo',
- **react-native version**:" 63.4 "

I would like to use it in this way:

```
import { toHaveProp } from '@testing-library/jest-native';

expect.extend({ toHaveProp });
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Module '"../../../../../../node_modules/@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"' has no exported member 'toHaveProp'.
```

any idea ?

Comment: What's your `@testing-library/jest-native` version?

Comment: @juliomalves the last one "^3.4.3"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok if i put it `import '@testing-library/jest-native';` on the top of my test file , that works

Comment: Thank you! This was the last step I was missing.

Comment: Great if that could help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to import it in every test file, and my setup (using expo) was not working adding it in `setupFilesAfterEnv` so I did the following from the [official Github](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-native).

> Import @testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect once (for instance in your tests setup file) and you're good to go:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and to me what worked is simply adding the following to the Jest config:

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect'],
```

I didn't need to write `expect.extend`, but simply `toHaveStyle` and other functions were available when I wrote dot; for example:

```
expect(getByTestId('containerView')).toHaveStyle;
```

The `toHaveStyle` was now simply here WITHOUT specially imported `toHaveStyle` above in the imports. It is worth noting that I also did have to import `jest-native` in my test files, as [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66060280/3025856) is suggesting:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-native';
```

Comment: Please pay attention to your formatting when posting an answer. I've edited your answer to help clarify the explanation and improve the readability. Take a look at my change to ensure it is consistent with your intention—there were a couple of places where I needed to interpret your meaning.